# Smoothing in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have this ggplot

```
ggplot(dt.1, aes(x=pctOAC,y=NoP, fill=Age)) +
    geom_bar(stat="identity",position=position_dodge()) +
    geom_smooth(aes(x=pctOAC,y=NoP, colour=Age), se=F, method="loess",show_guide = FALSE,lwd=0.7) +
    theme(legend.position=c(.2,0.8))
```

[image]

```
dt1 <- structure(list(Age = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("o80", "u80"), class = "factor"), NoP = c(47L, 5L, 33L, 98L, 287L, 543L, 516L, 222L, 67L, 14L, 13L, 30L, 1L, 6L, 17L, 30L, 116L, 390L, 612L, 451L, 146L, 52L), pctOAC = c(0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100)), .Names = c("Age", "NoP", "pctOAC"), row.names = c(NA, -22L), class = "data.frame")
```

I would like to have the smooth lines constrained to lie above zero, perhaps something similar to a kernel density. In fact if I **had** the underlying data, I expect a kernel density is **exactly** what I would want, but I only have the aggregated data. Is there any way to do this ? I tried using different `method=` in the `geom_smooth`, but the small dataset seems to prevent it. I wondered about using `stat_function` but I don't have much clue about how to proceed with finding a suitable function to plot.

Comment: Isn't there a geom_density???

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Another possibility is to use `method="glm"` with a spline curve and a log link (i.e. also tried `method="gam"`, but its automatic complexity adjustment wanted to reduce the wiggliness too much:

```
library(splines)
ggplot(dt.1, aes(x=pctOAC,y=NoP, fill=Age)) +
    geom_bar(stat="identity",position=position_dodge()) +
    geom_smooth(aes(colour=Age), se=F,
                method="glm",
                formula=y~ns(x,8),
                family=gaussian(link="log"),
                show_guide = FALSE,lwd=0.7) +
    theme(legend.position=c(.2,0.8))
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

How about `geom_density()`?

```
ggplot(dt1, aes(x=pctOAC,y=NoP, colour=Age, fill=Age)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity",position=position_dodge()) +
  geom_density(stat="identity", fill=NA) +
  theme(legend.position=c(.2,0.8))
```

[image]

Comment: It doesn't look like this is actually smoothing at all?  Nevertheless, even if it's only interpolating, is there any way to convince `ggplot2` to evaluate it at intermediate points, equivalent to the `n` argument in `density`?

Comment: in retrospect I think `stat_identity` doesn't make a to of sense with `geom_density`